# Htaccess not returning 404 response code

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm having problems trying to get my site to return the proper 404 response code with .htaccess.

When I try to put:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.sitename.com/404.html
```

It loads me a 404 page, but it does not give the proper 404 code. I used https://httpstatus.io/ to check my page, and it says it returns a 200 response code.

However when I try to put:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

On a page I know is missing and should return a 404, I instead get an 'Aw snap!' page from Chrome (and Firefox also gives me an error).

I'm not exactly sure what I should do to fix this. I'm not sure if this is relevant but I use Adobe Muse for my site.

Comment: The second example should return 404 error status. try clearing your browser cache

Comment: I've done that but still no change.